# How to create android app with app widget in single application to display a activity of application on widget

Tags: android, widget

I have already done one android application which is store person name and phone number.

Now I have to develop one widget for this application to show this activity on widget (person name, phone number) with button(button is present on the app activity just want to display the same on widget).

Requirements:

Single application with app and widget.
When I click on a button which is in the widget, it will perform the same task as in application.
Widget data should synchronize with my app when the data in the application is changed.
How could I design this widget? Any guidelines? I have to use verticle scrollview.
I have done a simple widget demo but I don't know how to display activity of my application.

Please share your experience and give some idea about my widget and application.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about what you are planning to do, but please allow me to explain in 2 points:

**1.Data sharing with app and appwidget**

Usually appwidget is controlled by a Service, and the Service can have run in the same process with app (Activity). So they can share a cache if you want to implement one, or using database as well as shared preference can be good ideas if you want to hold these data in storage.

Please note, appwidget itself is displayed in different process with your app. It is displayed by the Home application. But your Service can control what the widget should display by setting the contents in a RemoteView and sent it to the Home application.

**Conclusion: To share data between app and appwidget, just like sharing the data with a Activity and a Service within one application.**

**2.Displaying Activity when user tap on appwidget**

This is very simple, set a PendingIntent which will start one of your Activity into a appwidget button. **Done**

You may want to let your Activity become transparent to improve the user experience.

Hope above helps.